# Move a floating point constant to a xmm register

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Good morning/afternoon wizards of the internet

For clarification im using Visual Studio with custom made assembly functions, that why i sometime say "i could create a variable..."

I am trying to move a floating point constant(0.9856) to an xmm register in MASM, something along the lines of what you would do to move 8 to eax

`mov eax,08d`
I already tried what the visual studio compiler does to create a float variable with that value

```
movss       xmm0,dword ptr [__real@3f7c5048 (07FF6B347AC38h)]
```

but i get an error message saying : "undefined symbol : __real@3f7c5048"

I know i could create a float variable with the value i want, get the pointer, and then assign to an xmm register the contents of that memory position, but i dont want to make my function calls over filled with parameters

I also tried what other forum posts give as a solution

```
mov       rax,07FF6A19DAC38h
movd    xmm1,rax
```

PS: i got that value from what the compiler does

but i dont get the value I want when assigning the contents of xmm1 to a float variable in c++

any tips/pointers/critics are welcome

Thanks in advance dear low level dwellers

Comment: The usual solution is indeed to place the constant in memory somewhere (e.g. in the data section) and then to load it.  You have to define your own constant and symbol.  There is no automatism to have the assembler do that for you.

Comment: You forgot to copy the `dd 0.9856` definition for that symbol in `.rdata` that MSVC also emits, if you look at its asm listing output on https://godbolt.org/